# For folder input Reactjs is not accepting "webkitdirectory directory" as atttributes to input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-io, io

I am trying to have a folder input instead of file input. I want to select a folder and not just a single file. I tried available solutions from already asked question, but non of them worked. This is what I tried

**Tried**

```
 <input id="myInput" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

**Faced Problems**

1). I am working on react and react highlights "webkitdirectory directory" and says "attribute directory no allowed here". Seems like react is rejecting these attributes. How to solve this?

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59818

2). I have read that Linux doesn't support folder selection. I am working on linux and I cannot select a folder. Is the problem because of this? How can I solve it?

I think if 1st one gets solved then things will be fine. Please suggest a solution or work around for this.

Comment: _"I have read that Linux doesn't support folder selection."_ *nix allows selecting directories at `<input type="file">` element. Can you include link to the documentation that you are referencing at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 added the link

Comment: Are you trying to select both directories and individual files at same `<input type="file">` element?

Comment: I am trying chrome. I think the parent issue is 1st point. After we solve 1st,Then we can rectify that linux is supporting it or not.

Comment: chromium, chrome and firefox support directory upload at *nix. Though chromium and firefox provide different functionality at rendered `<input type="file">` elements. Not sure what issue is? Specific to `reactjs`?

Comment: Yes it is reactjs issue. I get "attribute directory no allowed here". This inspection highlights unknown HTML tag attributes as invalid, and lets mark such attributes as Custom to avoid highlighting them as invalid.

Comment: This is what it says highlighting webkitdirectory directory

Comment: Have not tried `reactjs`. `directory` should be `webkitdirectory`, `allowdirs` for firefox. chromium, chrome do not yet recognize `directory` attribute alone without `webkit` prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144160/discussion-between-apurvg-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<input type="file" directory="" webkitdirectory="" multiple />
```